# Android View is NULL after sending callback

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

After I authenticate the user (using volley library), my `ServerConnection` class sends a callback with the name of the user to my `Fragment`. I want to show the name of the user in a `TextView` but the app always crashes.

```
public class DrawerFragment extends Fragment implements ServerConnection.AuthenticationSuccessful {


TextView vDrawerName;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_default, container, false);
    vDrawerName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawerName);
    vDrawerName.setText("Test"); // works
    ListView drawerList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
    drawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            new String[]{"Hallo", "test"}));
    return view;
}



@Override
public void onSuccess(String firstName, int id) {
        vDrawerName.setText(firstName); // view is null
}

}
```

ServerConnection.class

```
private AuthenticationSuccessful successful;

public ServerConnection(FragmentActivity activity, SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.sharedPreferences = sharedPreferences;
    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity);
    successful = new DrawerFragment();
}

public void authenticate(){
    //...
    successful.onSuccess("Name", 1);
}

public interface AuthenticationSuccessful {
    public void onSuccess(String firstName, int id);
}
```

In MainActivity

```
ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(this,
                getSharedPreferences(ServerConnection.LOGIN_PREFERENCE, 0));
connection.authenticate();
```

logcat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.polat.mete.worknote.fragments.DrawerFragment.onSuccess(DrawerFragment.java:40)
        at com.polat.mete.worknote.ServerConnection$3.onResponse(ServerConnection.java:124)
        at com.polat.mete.worknote.ServerConnection$3.onResponse(ServerConnection.java:116)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5223)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `TextView vDrawerName;` to `final TextView vDrawerName;`?

Comment: In server connection you created a new fragment *instance*. Did you actually commit it in a transaction before attempting to call `onSuccess`? The fragment doesn't depend on the connection, so commit it outside and before.

Comment: @Leigh It isn't possible to set a object as final globally if your instance the object locally.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
public class DrawerFragment extends Fragment implements ServerConnection.AuthenticationSuccessful {

TextView vDrawerName;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_default, container, false);
    vDrawerName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawerName);
    vDrawerName.setText("Test"); // works
    ListView drawerList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
    drawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            new String[]{"Hallo", "test"}));
    return view;
}



@Override
public void onSuccess(String firstName, int id) {
        ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawerName)).setText(firstName); // view is null
}

}
```